# PermissionDenied: 403 IAM permission 'dialogflow.sessions.detectIntent'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, chatbot, service-accounts, google-cloud-iam, dialogflow-cx

Getting the following error when using a python script to call dialogflow's detectIntent function.

google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 IAM permission 'dialogflow.sessions.detectIntent' on 'projects/*project_name*/locations/us-central1/agents/*agent_id*' denied.

Core code for credentials and connecting:

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(environment.credential_path)
session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient(credentials=credentials, client_options=client_options)
response = session_client.detect_intent(request=request)
```

I set a breakpoint and confirmed that the session_client._transport._credentials looks correct and the service_account_email is correct. I also checked in the Policy Troubleshooter and it is confirmed that the allow permission is set for the service account for dialogflow.sessions.detectIntent (though the deny policy is set to Unknown but only because it is not supported and shouldn't be denied anyways).

So it seems that the code is using the correct service account and the service account has the correct permissions so I am at a loss for what could be causing the 403 and/or what steps to check/take next. I have also confirmed that the Dialogflow API service is enabled. Any ideas/help?